# std.json - A bit confused with TRUE, FALSE and NULL values

Tags: json, d, phobos

I was looking over the `std.json` library as part of program I am working on, and I'm a bit confused about how to get data out of `JSONValue`s whose types are inferred as `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`.

For example, if I parse the following JSON:

```
{
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

I can then extract the string held in the attribute `"foo"` by doing something like:

```
auto json = parseJSON("/path/to/json/example.json");
auto foo_attr = json["foo"].str;
```

But suppose instead that I had JSON like this:

```
{
    "foo" : false,
    "bar" : true,
    "baz" : null
}
```

What would I need to do to get at the attribute values of `"foo"`, `"bar"` and `"baz"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the variable's type.

```
auto json = parseJSON("/path/to/json/example.json");
bool foo = json["foo"].type == JSON_TYPE.TRUE;
bool bar = json["bar"].type == JSON_TYPE.TRUE;
bool bazIsNull = json["baz"].type == JSON_TYPE.NULL;
```

Of course, if you expect that values might have other types, you'll need extra checks.